# apply methods when adding to R lists without global scoping

Tags: r, global-variables, purrr

I'd like to use [`purrr::walk()`](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) to push objects on to a [flifo stack](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=flifo).  Looping works correctly, but my implementation of walk() doesn't.

```
requireNamespace("flifo")

cards       <- letters[1:5]
deck_loop   <- flifo::fifo()
deck_purrr  <- flifo::fifo()

# Looping works correctly   
for( card in cards ) {
  flifo::push(deck_loop, card)
}
message("Deck size: ", as.integer(flifo::size(deck_loop) / 96), " cards")
# Returns: "Deck size: 5 cards"

# This version of calling purrr::walk() doesn't work.
purrr::walk(cards, function(card) flifo::push(deck_purrr, card))
message("Deck size: ", as.integer(flifo::size(deck_purrr) / 96), " cards")
# Returns: "Deck size: 0 cards"
```

I think the issue is related to how the fifo [uses a list](https://github.com/paulponcet/flifo/blob/master/R/new.R) to hold objects and [`push()`](https://github.com/paulponcet/flifo/blob/master/R/push.R).  Inside this third function, `l3` isn't modified unless the global assignment `<<-` is used.  Is there some trick with the environment of `deck_purr`?

```
l3 <- list()
fx3 <- function(a) {
  # l3[[length(l3) + 1L]] <- a # Won't work b/c it's not a global assignment
  l3[[length(l3) + 1L]] <<- a
}
purrr::walk(11:15, function( x ) fx3(x))
```

Incidentally, the [rstack package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rstack) (which doesn't implement a LIFO stack) doesn't have this problem; I'm presuming it's because its [R6 internals](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=R6) handle the scoping of the stack's [internal list](https://github.com/MangoTheCat/rstack/blob/master/R/package.R) differently.

```
deck_rstack  <- rstack::stack$new()
purrr::walk(cards, function(card) deck_rstack$push(card))
message("Deck size: ", deck_rstack$size(), " cards")
```

*edit July 2018*: The flifo developer addressed this in https://github.com/paulponcet/flifo/issues/1.

Answer (score 0):

The [dequer](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dequer) package supports FIFO and loading individual elements with `purrr::walk()`.  The [`pushback()`](https://github.com/wrathematics/dequer/blob/master/R/pushing.r) method is moving these elements around [with C pointers underneath](https://github.com/wrathematics/dequer/blob/1ed009322f3ba6e30014d84b969bdfe0c77e02cf/src/constructor.c#L56-L66).

```
deck_dequer <- dequer::queue()
purrr::walk(cards, function(card) dequer::pushback(deck_dequer, card))
message("Deck size: ", length(deck_dequer), " cards")
```

Although this addresses the specific case of [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) structures, I'm still curious if there's a solution to the larger original issue if `purrr::walk()` can act like a top-level `for()` loop with the stack's elements.